# Partial derivative of $x^TA^TAx$ with respect to $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

I'm trying to evaluate $\nabla_{A} x^TA^TAx$ for vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$. I evaluated it elementwise and was wondering if there is a clean, closed form formula for this?

Comment: Please have a look to equation (92) here: https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf

Comment: my bad, equation (77): so the answer I guess would be $2Axx^T$

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply!

Comment: Setting $g(x)=x^tBx$, $g(x+h)=(x+h)^t B(x+h)=x^tBx+h^Bx+x^tBh +h^Bh$. Notice that $\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{|h^tBh|}{\|h\|}=0$. Hence $g'(x)$ is the linear operator that maps $h\mapsto h^tBx+x^tBh=h^t(B+B^t)x$. In your case $B=A^tA$ and the rest is easy.

Comment: This question would benefit from added context, and will likely be closed otherwise. For example, simply telling us where you got the problem from or explaining what you tried would be a big step forward! (For further feedback/help with asking questions, you can ask [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback).)

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
$The Matrix Cookbook is a wonderful resource, but you may want to verify the result for yourself.

The matrix inner product is a convenient notation for the trace
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F \\
}$$
When applied to vector arguments, it corresponds to the usual dot product.

For typing convenience, introduce the vector $\;w=Ax$.

Write the objective function using the above notation.

Then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \big\|Ax\big\|^2_F = w:w \\
d\phi &= 2w:dw = 2w:dA\,x = 2wx^T:dA \\
\grad{\phi}{A} &= 2wx^T = 2Axx^T \\
}$$